# Prove that $\gcd(k,mn) = 1$ iff $\gcd(k,n) = 1$ and $\gcd(k,m) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Reverse direction I have:

By $k,n$ being coprime, there are integers $x,y$ such that $xk + ny=1$. Likewise, we can write $ak+bm=1$. Hence, we have:

$$xk+ny = ak+bm = 1.$$

But from here, I am not sure how to proceed. Likewise, with forward direction. Just need a hint to continue.

Comment: Bezout provides a way to go in both cases. In the reverse direction, use the fact that if $xk+ny = ak+bm = 1$, then $(xk+ny)(ak+bm) = 1$. In the forward direction, suppose $gcd(k, nm) = 1$. Then there exist integers $x, y$ such that $xk+y(nm) = 1$. But we can rewrite this as $xk+(yn)m = 1$, so $gcd(k, m) = 1$; likewise with $n$.